# Lab 10 Git Immersion

Tags: git, git-log

I'm new at git and got to git immersion which is a cool way to learn it but in [lab 10](http://gitimmersion.com/lab_10.html) it gives "the ultimate log format"

```
git log --pretty=format:'%h %ad | %s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
```

I try to run it in git 1.9.4.msysgit.2 and doesn't recognize the las part of the command:

```
%s%d [%an]' --graph --date=short
```

any ideas? is git immersion not updated?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not the tutorial that is out of date, but your git client. You mention that you're on version 1.9.4, yet the most recent git version is 2.8.1 (stable). [Git for windows](https://git-for-windows.github.io/) offers that version. Installing that should do the trick.

Comment: Nice! Typically it then makes sense to 'accept' the answer, so that others see that the question is resolved without scrolling through the comments :-)

Comment: sorry, kind of new on stack :P there it is!